# Unable to Convert the message

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, ibm-mq, tibco-ems

I need to add a message header to the meassage which i will push to the Tibco and IBM MQ server. Please find below the code :

`(TextMessage)message).setStringProperty(rs.getString(2),value);`

the above code adds header to message. but when i convert the message i get the below exception

`error:com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTextMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessag`

Anyother option to add mesage header to a message is also appriciated.

Comment: What is the type of the "message" variable ? (please send the declaration line)

Comment: @GhislainCote Message variable is `object` Type. and others all are in String

Comment: I seriously doubt that `message` has the dynamic(!) type Object. From the error I bet it has the dynamic type `com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTextMessage`
For some reason TibjmsTextMessage does not seem to implement TextMessage, thus the cast fails.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the `message` variable type from `Object` type to `javax.jms.TextMessage`?

Since `com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTextMessage implements javax.jms.TextMessage`, that MAY allow the conversion.

If this answer does not help, please supply more source code and context on the error (stacktrace, EMS message content, etc.)

FYI, this declaration was extracted from the EMS tibjms.jar file:

```
public class com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTextMessage
    extends com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsMessage
    implements javax.jms.TextMessage, java.io.Serializable, 
               java.lang.Cloneable, com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxConst{[...]}
```